# how to get session value in asmx method asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i get session value to the web method . I have tried but it giving me the object reference not set to be instance of object . Any body know the issue .i want to get first method session value in my second method .
how can i do it . i am getting value form my ajax function to my asmx page in getid method . but i want that it to be in my second method as parameter so that i can perform search process

```
  The full code is here 
   **javascript code**
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn').on('click', function () {
        
            $.ajax({
                url: 'EmployeeWebService.asmx/GetEmployees',
                data: { id: '2'}, //this is id i want to get
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'post',
                success: function (data) {

                  


                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }

            });

           
        });
    });
          </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#btn').on('click', function () {

                $('#datatables').DataTable({

                columns: [
                    { 'data': 'Id' },
                    { 'data': 'FirstName' },
                    { 'data': 'LastName' },
                    { 'data': 'Gender' },
                    { 'data': 'JobTitle' },
                        {
                            data: "TotalQuestions", render: function 
                (data, type, row) {
                                return '<button type="button" data-id="  ' 
                + row.Gender + '  " class="get_tsk" style="background- 
                  color:steelblue;color:white;border:none;">view</button> '
                            }
                        },
                    
                ],
                bServerSide: true,
                sAjaxSource: 'EmployeeWebService.asmx/GetEmployees',
                sServerMethod:'post'
          
                });



                });
            });

       </script>
   **first Method**
```

**First Method**
string nameofid;

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public void GetId(string id)
    {
       
         Session["nameofid"] = id;

    }
  **Second Method** 

    public void GetEmployees(string id,int iDisplayLength,int 
     iDisplayStart,int 
      iSortCol_0,string sSortDir_0,string sSearch)
     {
        int displayLength = iDisplayLength;
        int displayStart = iDisplayStart;
        int sortCol = iSortCol_0;
        string sortDir = sSortDir_0;
        string search = sSearch;

        int filteredRows = 0;

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        //  
        List<Employee> listEmployee = new List<Employee>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetEmployees", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value =id;

            SqlParameter paramDisplayLength = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@DisplayLength",
                Value = displayLength
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDisplayLength);

            SqlParameter paramDisplayStart = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@DisplayStart",
                Value = displayStart
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDisplayStart);

            SqlParameter paramSortCol = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@SortCol",
                Value = sortCol
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramSortCol);

            SqlParameter paramSortDir = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@SortDir",
                Value = sortDir
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramSortDir);

            SqlParameter paramSearchString = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Search",
                Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? null : search
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramSearchString);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                filteredRows = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["TotalCount"]);
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                employee.FirstName = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();
                employee.LastName = rdr["LastName"].ToString();
                employee.Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
                employee.JobTitle = rdr["JobTitle"].ToString();
                listEmployee.Add(employee);
            }
        }

        var result = new
        {
            iTotalRecords = GetEmployeeTotalCount(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredRows,
            aaData = listEmployee
        };

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(result));
    }
    private int GetEmployeeTotalCount()
    {
        int totalEmployees = 0;
        string cs = 
          ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from 
         tblEmployees", con);
            con.Open();
            totalEmployees = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        return totalEmployees;

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check my below screenshot and follow the steps:

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

Comment: Please share your code as a text instead of image. That would improve your answer.

Comment: Can you check my answer

Comment: i am using jquery ajax functions!.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Route Config File below Line :

   routes.IgnoreRoute("{*x}", new { x = @".*.asmx(/.*)?" });
2. Add WebService File :

   ```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionDetail"] != null)
        {
            string _SessionData = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionDetail"]);
        }

        return "Hello World";
    }
   ```
3. Assign Session Value :

   ```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Session["SessionDetail"] = "Value for Session";
            return View();
        }
   ```

Comment: Share your full code, So I can check and get back to you.

Comment: Check my another post answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, you using this:

```
Session["nameofid"] = id;
```

and then this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["nameofid"].ToString();
```

The next issue is how are you calling these methods? If you using say jQuery.ajax?

Remember they are async calls. If you call to set and then in the same code stub call the 2nd routine, it  will often fail since such calls are async.

You "could"  consider using async = false in the ajax calls, but browers (and jQuery) is now warning that non async  calls will not be allowed or supported.

What this means? Be carefull, and if you do a web method call to SET a value, then you need to split out the code that follows to a seperate routine.

we used to do:

```
           function ShowPdf(pID) {

               //  set/save the  id
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   async: false,
                   url: 'ProjectUpload.aspx/SetChoice',
                   data: '{strSess:"ProofID", strValue:' + pID + '}',
                   contentType: "application/json",
                   datatype: "json"
               });
               // MORE code  here - and MAYBE some code that calls or MIGHT
               // use the value based on the ABOVE web method call
               // but we CAN'T use async: false anymore!
               // so we CAN NOT write code folling here that needs or 
               // assumes the above call is finished - this code does not
               // wait.
```

So, above code becomes this:

```
           function ShowPdf(pID) {

               //  set/save the  id
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   success: ShowPdf2,     <- AFTER code  now is moved to this rouine
                   url: 'ProjectUpload.aspx/SetChoice',
                   data: '{strSess:"ProofID", strValue:' + pID + '}',
                   contentType: "application/json",
                   datatype: "json"
               });
           }
           function ShowPdf2() {

               // split out due to we have to wait async
               // for web call to complete. This code ONLY runs WHEN
              // the above web call is 100% done. Even if web server is slow today!
               // MUST  set session() ProofID before calling this routine

               // show a dialog  in this page pdfdiv
                var mydiv = $('#pdfdiv');

                mydiv.dialog({
                 autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Proofing: ', width: '100%',
                 position: {
                    my: "center top",
                    at: "center top+80"
                     },close: myempty,
                        dialogClass: 'dialog-no-close'
                    });
                    mydiv.load('../PDF1.aspx');
                    // Open the dialog
                    mydiv.dialog('open');
               // }
           }
```

So, the above code was failing since the following the web call would start running before the session() set ajax call was done.

Setting async: false DID work well, but in the browser debug, we saw warnings that async:false will soon not be supported in jQuery (or web browsers). So, you wire up a routine to run when the async call is done and move out the code that follows to that routine so, the code that follows was moved out and called by the jQuery  (success: event).

So, it not clear how/when/where your code calls the first web method, but if any code call FOLLOWS to check/see/grab/get/look at the session() value to be return from the 2nd web method? You have to deal with the async issue.

and depending on your imports (using for c# folks), then if you need to include the namespace before using session() in a web method.

I find I have to use this:

```
    HttpContext.Current.Session(strSess) = strValue
```

So, I would use the same name space reference in both your web methods - is it NOT AT ALL clear why you left out the name space in one code stub, but put it in the other.

As noted, it also not clear how your js is testing/getting the session() value, but as noted, the first web call to set the session() will NOT wait, and you find sometimes that when you call the 2nd routine to get the session(), the first routine may well not yet have finished (since the calls are async).